# Print names based on zip code

Tags: linux

I got a text file that´s formatted like this:

```
29:Jan:Høiberg:Darres gate 22:0175:Oslo:69215348
```

Based on this i want to print the first and last name IF the zip code starts with 11, 12 or 13 in that text file.
Fairly new to linux, so any help on how to do this would be great.
Doing this in terminal.

Comment: Ok and in which language? Bash? Python?

Comment: Sorry. This is to be done in terminal.

Comment: You can run a python script in a terminal, too ;) so the question is do you have a file with some lines? Or how is you case?

Comment: Oh, ok I didnt know that. For the moment i just have a .txt file with the data on the persons, and another file with the lines that should do what i am trying to do.

Comment: All I got right now, is: cut -d: -f2,3 persondata.txt
Wich prints out the first and last name in the terminal when running "bash".

Comment: Which field is the zip code? 5 or 7?  (I'd guess it's the 4 digit one, but I don't know what country you're in, nor much about the zip coding scheme)

Comment: The zip code is number 5. So you are right, it's the 4 digit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main "old school UNIX" ways of approaching this. One is the all-in-one `awk` approach, which is powerful and clean, but fewer people are fluent in it.

Another is the piping-together-text-utils approach.

First we want to filter out the lines you're interested in. We can pipe that output to another command to print the fields you want.

So:

```
egrep '^([^:]*:){4}1[123]' file.txt
```

I've used `egrep` instead of `grep` because it gives us `{4}` for "repeated 4 times". So that's

- `^` -- start of line
- `[^:]*` -- zero or more occurences of any char except ':'
- followed by a ':'
- `{4}` -- repeated 4 times (note `()` grouping the part to be repeated)
- followed by a `1`
- followed by `1`,`2` or `3` -- `[123]`

Test this on your data before adding the next step; extracting the parts you need. In the comments you show you already know how to use `cut`:

```
egrep '^([^:]*:){4}1[123]' file.txt | cut -d: -f2,3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient one, but will work, although one thing to note is that, as you didn't specify which **column in your data represented zip code**, I assumed it was **column 5**, i.e. column with value `0175` in it, although the following code can be changed accordingly if my assumed column number is not representing zip code. Run this in your terminal:

```
awk -F: 'IF match($5, /11.*/) > 0 || match($5, /12.*/) > 0 || match($5, /13.*/) > 0 {split($4, a, " "); print "Name is: ",$3, a[1], "with code:", $5}' persondata.txt
```

And when run on sample data `persondata.txt`:

```
29:Jan:Høiberg:Darres gate 22:0175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f1:l1 gate 22:1175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f2:l2 gate 22:1275:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f3:l3 gate 22:0175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f4:l4 gate 22:01375:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f5:l5 gate 22:12:Oslo:11215348
```

The output is:

```
Name is:  f1 l1 with code: 1175
Name is:  f2 l2 with code: 1275
Name is:  f4 l4 with code: 01375
Name is:  f5 l5 with code: 12
```

If you only want to print names, and not the codes then replace `print "Name is: ",$3, a[1], "with code:", $5` with `print "Name is: ",$3, a[1];`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**awk**

```
$ awk -F: '$5~/1[123][0-9]*/ {gsub(/[ ].*/,"",$4); print $3,$4}' f1
```

If your 5th field matches this regex then print firstname `$3` and lastname `$4` until space.

Taking input file from @tkhurana96. Thanks

**Input:**

```
29:Jan:Høiberg:Darres gate 22:0175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f1:l1 gate 22:1175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f2:l2 gate 22:1275:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f3:l3 gate 22:0175:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f4:l4 gate 22:01375:Oslo:11215348 
29:Jan:f5:l5 gate 22:12:Oslo:11215348
```

**Output**:

```
f1 l1
f2 l2
f4 l4
f5 l5
```